# React Gulpfile watchify not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp, browserify, watchify

I'm following a tutorial on Reactjs and we're using a Gulpfile to update the dependancies and build a single javascript file using browserify.

For some reason there is no update whenever I change a line in a file..
This is my code.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var watchify = require('watchify');
var reactify = require('reactify');

gulp.task('default', function() {
  var bundler = watchify(browserify({
    entries: ['./src/app.jsx'],
    transform: [reactify],
    extensions: ['.jsx'],
    debug: true
  }));

  function build(file) {
    if (file) gutil.log('Recompiling ' + file);
    return bundler
      .bundle()
      .on('error', gutil.log.bind(gutil, 'Browserify Error'))
      .pipe(source('main.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
  };
  build();
  bundler.on('update', build);
});
```

This is my folder structure

[image]

Comment: It seems that the issue is with Vagrant and Homestead, When I run the gulp task on my machine it's working. weird!

Answer (score 1):

Watchify may have issues to detect the changes on certain filesystem setups and virtualization.

See https://github.com/substack/watchify/issues/120

try Watchify 3.0.0 as it seems to use a polling for NFS